# jQuery Selector [name=value] doesn't work

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, jquery-selectors

I'm a newbie to jQuery. I met a issue when using the [name=value] selector.
Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="number"/>
```

Very simple, right?
And here is the JS:

```
$("input").val(100);
$("input[value='100']").val(200)​
```

The result is: the first line of the script works, but not the second line.(Chrome, FF, IE9)
The both line works in IE8.
How this happens? BTW, I'm using jQuery1.7.2. Or you can just test the above code on http://jsfiddle.net/wzKNV/

Comment: Quick and dirty, this is the method that I would use. val() is a property and not an attribute, meaning that the attribute selector won't work in this scenario. I've created a jsfiddle, and cloned the element to show you the separation. http://jsfiddle.net/7PZdt/

Answer (score 6):

The *attribute-equals* selector checks the *attribute*, but the `.val()` only changes the property, so the selector doesn't see the update.

The native `querySelectorAll` method that jQuery/Sizzle defaults to enforces this "attribute-only" behavior.

If you break the selector for `querySelectorAll`, so that Sizzle must be used, it will work...

```
// v------made it a non-standard Sizzle selector
$(":input[value='100']").val(200);
```

This is because Sizzle selectors aren't necessarily compliant with the `qSA` selectors. Of course this changes the meaning of the selector a little, but is useful for illustration.

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/wzKNV/3/

---

To keep it using standard selectors *(which is a good idea IMO)*, you can use `filter()` instead...

```
$("input").filter(function() { return this.value === '100'; })
          .val(200);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/wzKNV/4/

Comment: Well, really teach me a lot on both jQuery and qSA selectors.

Comment: Strange why both lines in the original code would work in IE8, though, as it also implements the Selectors API. There's probably something else going on in that browser.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Appears as though adding a property to an element *(or modifying one)* in IE8 also modifies the attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/9bCCR/ Even the custom property showed up using `getAttribute`. IE9 seems to behave correctly.

Comment: This answer solves a problem with `$("input:hidden[value=true]").length`. Change to `$("input:hidden").filter(function() { return this.value === "true"; }).length` for IE.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
<input type="nubmer" disabled="disabled" value="100" />​ // your fiddle have no `value`
```

then

```
$("input[value='100']").val(200)​​​​​​​
```

will work